# Htaccess alias for multilanguage site without redirect

Tags: .htaccess, dns, alias, multilingual

I have a multilingual site

- example.com - english
- example.com/it/ - italian

I need example.it/(.*) to handle requests on example.com/it/$1 without redirect to example.com. Just to stay on example.it and handle all request to example.com/it/

Comment: All you need to do is a rewrite instead of a redirect. You select the "language code" from the url and pass it as additional request parameter or (much better) environment variable. What is the problem here? This is all explained in the excellent documentation of the rewriting module.

Comment: Can you please give me an example please ?

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the documentation of Apaches [rewrite module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) these examples should point you into the right direction.

Example using an addition request parameter `lang`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteLog /var/log/apache2/rewrite_log
RewriteLogLevel 3
RewriteRule ^/(it|fr|no)/(.*)$  /$2?lang=$1  [L,QSA]
```

The rules take care that all requests to http(s)://example.com//... are internally rewritten, so that http(s)://example.com/...?lang= is called. Take care to use only relative links when sending out links.

Example using an environment variable `LANG` which can be evaluated by some script or whatever:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteLog /var/log/apache2/rewrite_log
RewriteLogLevel 3
RewriteRule ^/(it|fr|no)(/.*)$  $2  [L,E=LANG:$1,QSA]
```

Note that I did *not* run this code, I just wrote it down, so you might have to adapt it slightly if some error is mentioned. Also try plaing around with the RewriteLogLevel (values 0-9), it really helps to understand what is going on inside the rewriting engine.